# How do I survive multiple gunshots?

Tags: hotline-miami-2

Playing through hotline miami 2 right now and I noticed that sometimes when I'm being shot at I can eat a bullet and not die. A shotgun blast not so much, but it seems like small arms fire isn't dropping me immediately. Is this a bug? If not, is there a wait time before you can take another shot?

something else of note too: yeah, it even makes a small blood splatter when this happens. I don't recall seeing anything about this, what gives?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug.

You should be able to take one bullet and survive, but two or more though, like you mentioned with the shotgun, is lethal.